# Replace or Handle "Go" Button on WebView

Tags: android, webview

I am having a WebView, which gets an HTML page from Server. The HTML page is not under my control. It can be anything. I just get the URL from Server, which I load using a WebView. Now The problem is :
For in some web pages I am getting a set of questions with Submit and Reset Button. So For Example: Having A TextView with Submit and Reset Button. When I focus on Textbox - KeyBoard opens with a Go Button. And If User presses the Go button the form data gets submitted, which I don't want. There is a Submit button for it, why should the go button do the same thing.

I have tried few things : 
- Disable GO button (I guess not Possible)
- Replace Go button with Enter (No Luck)
- Handle Go key press (No Luck)

Basically , If at all I want to disable/remove Go button from Keyboard.

Can anyone provide the possible solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can your web developer be able to change html code?

Comment: Nops. I don't have any control over pages. It's completely out of my control.

Comment: See my answer below for how to handle the Go key press.

Comment: @BrijeshThakur, did you get solution of this problem?

Comment: Hi Vic , I left that project a long back  :)

Answer (score 1):

WebView is outdated and is using AbsoluteLayout for rendering, which is deprecated long back on API V3 [Refer Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

I suppose the only way is to customize your soft keyboard,

refer to links below,

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html
- https://github.com/rciovati/Android-KeyboardView-Example

Comment: For one key it's not recommended to use complete new keyboard.

Comment: If you want your own custom IME Action for a Webview, then you need to extend the Keyboard and write your own IME action.

Answer (score 1):

please check out the following trick in Menifest.xml file for the activity which is having your webview

```
<activity android:name="..."
   ...
   android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"
   ...
</activity>
```

Comment: It will hide done button for all the views. I want to hide it only for webview. I have many edittext component in my application

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been successful in hiding the action button; however, you can easily change what it does.

```
public class MyWebView extends WebView
{
    public MyWebView(Context context) { super(context); }

    @Override public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo ei) {
        return new MyConnection(super.onCreateInputConnection(ei));
    }

    private class MyConnection extends InputConnectionWrapper
    {
        public MyConnection(InputConnection wrapped) { super(wrapped, false); }

        @Override public boolean performEditorAction(int action) {
            // do what you want
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try :)

Answer (score -1):

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

add this to the XML of your editText and it will replace it with a 'Done' button which simply closes the keyboard, it does not continue the form at all

Comment: On WebView , We don't have this option. I have only a webview which loads the page coming from server.

Comment: Nops still struggling with this. Need to do some hacking. Running out of time